# Advice - How to model detail list

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, xcode8

I am working with a single TableViewController

The object that is displayed in TableViewController is Task

```
struct Task{
   var type: String
   var children = [Task]()
}
```

I store the base Task objects in a TaskStore. The TaskStore has a member pivot, which I use to track the current element in TaskStore. By Default, pivot is -1, and the TableViewController lists all objects in TaskStore. When a user clicks on a row in the TableViewController, I update pivot with the selected row, and display the Task objects in TaskStore.sharedInstance.get(pivot).children. The back button sets pivot back to -1 and displays the base TaskStore.

I am worried that this is overly complex. It works without a real problem, but I do need to add an exception whenever Pivot is not -1.

Is there a more suitable way to display the children of a Task object in TaskStore without the need to create a new TableViewController?

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are unhappy is that you are doing a lot of complicated work in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to pick up the right data. It has to interpret the pivot and dive appropriately into the task store. I suggest you forget all that. Knowing how to dive into the task store is not the business of the table view's data source!

What I would do, therefore, is *separate* the overall hierarchical model from the table's actual data source. The data source, at any given moment, should just consist of an array of Tasks, a `[Task]`.

The problem then devolves into maintaining that array. When the user taps a row, you can replace that array of Tasks with whatever you like and call `reloadData`. In this way you maintain a direct correspondence between the table rows and tasks array. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` just asks for the info from that row of the Tasks array and it's done. Simple and clear.

Meanwhile, the work of knowing about your hierarchy all happens in the TaskStore, which is *not*, itself, the data source for the table. You might also need some sort of pointer into the TaskStore saying what the currently displayed parent is, but again, that bookkeeping will happen outside the array and outside the knowledge of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

You thus end up with *encapsulation of functionality*. The task store understands its internal hierarchy and how to fetch a desired set of tasks. The table view knows how to grab its rows using a simple one-to-one correspondence with the current tasks list.